# Show a fragment in an android widget

Tags: android, android-fragments, widget, fragment, kotlin

I want to show a widget, which loads an already working fragment in the widget space. I can't seem to find any documentation that handles loading fragments into a widget though? Can anyone help me out?

*widget_current.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<fragment android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/widgetCurrent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*widget_provider.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:minWidth="40dp"
                android:minHeight="40dp"
                android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
                android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_current"
                android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
                android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

*UpcomingEventWidgets.kt*

```
class UpcomingEventsWidget: AppWidgetProvider() {
override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds)

    val remoteView = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_current)

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, remoteView)
}
}
```

How do I go about loading the fragment into the remoteView?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please check out this documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout

This section specifically explained what a widget layout could use, it provides you a list with all available layout classes and widget classes. If anything that's not on the list, it will not work on a widget.

If you could dig into there class source file, some of them you should see  - @RemoteView at the beginning, this means the class is good for widget; if a class does not have this mark, it means you can't use it in widget.